# Elasticsearch: get all documents where array contains one of many values

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have the following document data structure in Elasticsearch:

```
{
    "topics": [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
}
```

I have a selection list where the user can filter which topics to show. When the user is OK with their filter, they will be presented with all documents that have any of the topics they selected in the array "topics"

I've tried the query

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
             "topics": ["a", "b"]
         }
    }
}
```

but this returns no results.

To expand on the query. For example, the list `["a", "b"]` would match the first, second and third objects in the array below.

[image: Example]

Is there a good way to do this in Elasticsearch? Obviously I could do multiple "match" queries but that's verbose as I have hundreds of topics

Edit: my mapping

```
{
    "fb-cambodia-post": {
        "mappings": {
            "scrapedpost": {
                "properties": {
                    "topics": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this work when using "a","b"... And not real data or bout cases

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index..  `GET index/_mapping`.

Comment: @Richa thanks. I've put the mapping as an edit to the OP

Comment: Yes just tested the example code works fine. The problem is most likely that you are using terms and you topics have multiple words. You can use "topics.keyword" I think it will work.

Comment: @FilipCordas that's it! `topics.keyword` works amazingly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Filip cordas mentioned you can use `topic.keyword` like.

```
 {
 "query": {
   "terms": {
     "topics.not_analyzed": [
        "A" , "B"
       ]
     }
   } 
 }
```

This will do `case sensitive` search .It Will look  for exact match. In case you want `case-insensitive` search you can use `query_string` like:

```
   {
    "query": {
     "query_string": {
       "default_field": "topics",
       "query": "A OR B"
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give some more info on the problem. The query with the data you added ("a", "b", "c") will work but if the topics have casing or multiple words it won't. This is due to the analyzer applied to the topic field. When you add a string value to ElasitcSearch it will by default use the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). The terms query only compares raw terms as they are put. So if you have something like "Topic1" in the document and you search "terms":["Topic1"] it won't return any value because the term in standard analyzer is lowercased and the query that will return the value will be `"terms":["topic1"]`. As of 5.0 elastic added the default "keyword" subfield that stores the data with the [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html). And it stores it as is no transformation is applied. Terms on that field `"terms.keyword":["Topic1"]` will get you the values, but  `"terms.keyword":["topic1"]` won't. What the match query dose is apply the filter on the input string as well and so you get the right result.